# TRIM command operability in Android 4.3

Tags: performance, 4.3-jelly-bean

Has anyone been able to confirm the **usage** and **operability** of the fstrim (TRIM) functionality in the latest Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) release? I have seen multiple articles mention the operability of the TRIM function when certain prerequisites are met in the latest release but I have also read a few comments/blogs where they state that the functionality was added and functional in Android 4.1.

Comment: From what I've read, it was added in 4.1, then disabled in 4.2. But that's pretty deep in the bowels of the OS, so I don't know how you're going to confirm it. Anecdotally speaking, my original Nexus 7 _does_ seem snappier now.

Comment: See the tracker on google source, [change #1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/c5771b5a4d66a0c7ca0e2cb1056e670f38b3834f) and [change #2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/743a5ec96cd54bdc06234be15cdde65296357a6a) So yes, its looking like its available and functional in 4.3

Comment: Very nice!! thanks for pointing me out to the source code itself. For what is worth, my device was in a unusable state a few days before the update. It has been two nights since I got the v4.3 and I can really tell you that my device now feels like new again. Go android!